# How to make a loop in assembler?

Tags: assembly

So i need to make system speaker beep and i got this

```
program lab1;   
begin  
asm   
MOV AL, 10110110b   
OUT 43h, AL  
MOV AX, 1000 ||<------ 1000 is N     
OUT 42h, AL  
MOV AL, AH  
OUT 42h, AL  
IN AL, 61h  
OR AL, 00000011b  
OUT 61h, AL  
MOV CX, 1000  
@N1:MOV DX, 0   
@N:NOP    
NOP    
NOP    
NOP   
DEC DX   
JNZ @N   
LOOP @N1    
IN AL, 61h    
AND AL, 11111100b    
OUT 61h, AL    
end    
end
```

and i need now to make all of this in a loop and also that N needs to get 10000 increasing by 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if that code beeps and you want to beep more then once, it's probably easiest to call it. Whenever you finally get something working, like your beep routine, leave it alone, put a RET on the end and call it.

As it is, AL gets corrupted by that first OUT call, so maybe you should pass the N in something else, BX, maybe.

```
MOV CX,10
MOV BX,1000
@nextN:
PUSH CX
PUSH BX
CALL beep;
POP BX
POP CX
ADD BX,1000
LOOP @nextN
RET
..

@beep:   
MOV AL, 10110110b   
OUT 43h, AL  
MOV AX, BX     
..
RET
```

PS - there is a 'homework' tab!